# Gmail can't receive html email with hyperlink

Tags: php, sendmail

I have to send email to any email account. I have written this code:

```
$sender = "Me";
$from = "me@domain.com";
$recipient = 'somebody@gmail.com';
$message = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href=\"http://www.something.net/verification.php?key=".$code."\">Click here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
";
$subject = "subject";
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: <".$from.">";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

My problem is, that if I send this message to a gmail account, the reciever doesnt get it. If I miss the hyperlink, or I just miss the '/' from the hyperlink, it works and I get the email.

I dont undarstend why? Something is missing from my code?

If I send this message to another domain, not gmail, it works fine. Just gmail doesnt show me the email with hyperlinks. Whats wrong? Any idea?

Comment: You're probably being marked as spam.

Comment: Spam filter comes to mind.

Comment: Must be goes in `spam` folder due to link. Have you check that ?

Comment: Your email html should not contain doctype, title, head, body etc. Just use a simple table structure and add your content.

Comment: "<a href='http://www.something.net/verification.php?key=".$code."'>Click here</a>"   

Just try it.

Comment: Is that really the content of your email? I'm not suprised it is being  treated as spam if all you're sending is a link with "click here". Try including some text that makes it look more legitimate - not just a link with "click here". Also, anchor text such as "Activate account" would be better.

Comment: I checked the spams and nothing... Thats not the whole email, I just redukated for you, that you can see the problem, the hyperlink. It is an email to confirm registration, so much more text is there. I tried to miss the html head and body part, but nothing changed. If I send it  to another email supplier it works correctly.

Comment: Try using single quotes in place of double quotes like this $message = ' ...

Comment: Hm... I used the Microsoft Outlook to check my emails. I dont know why but it didnt show me every spam letter. I checked my emails on the web(gmail) and I realized that there are my letters in the spamlist just Microsoft Outlook didnt want to download them or show them or I dont know... So now it seems, that I get the messages. The only problem is that why? Here is the whole message

Comment: <p>Dear '.$name.'!</p>
<p>To activate your account, please click on the following link or copy it into your browser to verify your registration.</p>
<p><a href=\'http://www.mywebpage.net/verification.php?key='.$code.'\'>http://www.mywebpage.net/verification.php?key='.$code.'</a></p>
<p>You can log in with this name and password:</p>
<p>Name: <b>'.$name.'</b></p>
<p>Password: <b>'.$pass1.'</b></p>
<p>
If you didn\'t register to us, ignore this letter and delete it from your mailbox.
</p>
So what can be the problem? Why it goes into spams?

Comment: According to my A-B testing when I included in the middle of body some HTML link - email was marked as SPAM. Does not matter that identical link used at the end of body was not causing problem. When I changed link to plain-text (not clickable) = INBOX. Also I noticed when I used 2 links in email = SPAM. Only one link = INBOX. So I think it is very stupid way in this case how google decides what is and what is not SPAM. So always test your new email templates for gmail users before using in production. Google is unpredictable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
```

and there corresponding closing taggs. Due to this you are facing problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help :( I dont get the email on my gmail address :/

Comment: try to send this to another email id then check whether this problem is only for Gmail

Comment: by the way why didn't you concatenated the values for $headers rather than imploding it.

Comment: I dont know :) I learnt this method :) It is the same by the way :)